# Upload file via HTTP from Android

Tags: android, file-upload, http-post, httprequest, mime-types

I'm trying to upload a XML file from an android device to a URL where it will be parsed. As an example I was given a curl command, which works:

```
curl -F xml=@templ2.xml "http://the-url-to-the-server"
```

But when I try to send something from my Android device I keep getting 'Invalid xml' as response. So based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3089498/668380) I created a php file for myself to try sending the file to, to see how it gets send:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

I've been trying all kinds of example code, but they all are rather similar, so I think they must be the right way to do it.

**Basically it comes down to this:** Either I send the file without declaring the MIME-type (see foo below), and then it get send as `"application/octet-stream"`, or I add a MIME-type `"text/xml"` or `"application/xml"` (see bar below) and then it ends up in the `$_REQUEST` of php, which I assume means it was not send as a file.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("foo", new FileBody(file));
reqEntity.addPart("bar", new FileBody(file, "text/xml"));

httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
    (
        [name] => templ2.xml
        [type] => application/octet-stream
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phppWbgl8
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 203
    )
)
Array
(
    [bar] => <foo>
            <bar>
            </bar>
            </foo>
)
```

Some related questions, which I have tried the code from:

- [Upload a file through an HTTP form, via MultipartEntityBuilder, with a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964288/upload-a-file-through-an-http-form-via-multipartentitybuilder-with-a-progress)
- [How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr/1068132#1068132)
- http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
reqEntity.addPart("bar", new FileBody(file, "text/xml"));
```

Try doing this

```
reqEntity.addPart("bar");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

Comment: Then you would change the content type of the entire request, which I believe should be some form of multipart. Anyway I tried it and didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. When I looked at the curl command, I realised `xml=@templ2.xml` means I had to use `xml` as name for the parameter. So

```
reqEntity.addPart("xml", new FileBody(file));
```